# Setting the size of a customized cursor in java

Tags: java, jframe, cursor

I have customized a cursor on a label component called ageLabel using the following code

```
ageLabel.setCursor(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/image1.jpg")).getImage(),new Point(5,5),"custom cursor"));
```

It works fine anyway but what I want to do is increase the size of the customized cursor. I have tried changing the point to (10,10) but the cursor size wouldn't change. I also tried changing the dimensions of the image that I used ,it still wouldn't change. I have searched through the internet but to no avail. Is It possible to resize the cursor in anyway? If it is how do I do that?
Thanks in advance for all helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Java's Image class has a built in function for scaling.

**Documentation:** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int)

**My approach to the problem:**

1. Split the line up into many to make it look a bit nicer (not necessary).
2. Add an extra method call to scale the image up.

#### Potential Solution:

```
    URL imageResource = getClass().getResource("/images/image1.jpg");
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageResource);
    Image image = imageIcon.getImage();

    // This is the important line that scales the image up!
    Image scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Cursor cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(scaledImage, new Point(5, 5), "Custom Cursor");
    ageLabel.setCursor(cursor);
```

---

*Afterthoughts:*

Remember to replace `newWidth` and `newHeight` with the values you want.

After you get it working, I'd even go further and extract some of this code into methods.

You might need to tweak your imports a bit if it isn't compiling.

I haven't tried running this code so I don't know if it works.